# Magento 2 - Browser Cache Leverage - AWS Cloudfront

Tags: amazon-web-services, magento, caching, amazon-cloudfront, response-headers

I'm working on Magento 2's speed optimization on one of my client's website.
On analyzing from gtmetrix.com, it says to use leverage browser cache. To achieve the same I followed following points:

1. I made changes in nginx configuration to set Cache-Control headers as follows:
   [nginx configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d4Lsh.png)
2. Following were the header after loading an image [headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g1taZ.png)
3. Made changes in AWS CloudFront behavior as follows [cloudfront configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XZUkN.png)
4. I've also checked the above selecting the "Use Origin Cache Headers".

What else is required to achieve the browser cache leverage?

Comment: Your question suggests that you are not satisfied with the results.  Can you clarify this?

Comment: Were there any image optimization warnings as well? Images increase the page weight significantly and are loaded in the last. You can check out this website analyzer tool - https://imagekit.io/website-analyzer to get more insights about image health.